# AngularJS using if statement with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new in angular, 
I want to check if condition like `channel=='new'` and wanna print `"will be available asap"`

```
<div ng-repeat="channel in channels">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="answer.content.args.channels[channel]"> {{channel}}
        </label>
    </div>
```

And i have tried to solve it using `ng-if="channel == 'new'"` , but it's not working for me.

Comment: inside the div: `<label ng-if="channel === 'new'">Will be available asap</label><label ng-if="channel !== 'new'"> your checkbox</label>`. The error in your ng-if is that you are assigning channel to 'new' (since you are using `=` while you need, instead, to compare it to a value.

Comment: You said you've tried using it but not shown how you tried it exactly? Can you show your actual attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to understand what you're trying to do, but I'm assuming you want to show "will be available asap' if channel is new, and some other text other way. You can do that like so:

`<input type="checkbox" ng-model="answer.content.args.channels[channel]">
    {{channel === 'new' ? 'will be available asap' : 'some other text here'}}
</input`

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between an expression (what we check) and an assignment: a double/triple `=`. With assignment we set the value to be something, with expression we compare them.

You should change your expression to `ng-if="channel == 'new'"`

On top of that, `ng-if` is a lot slower than `ng-show`, so you might want to use that instead. Also if you have multiple conditions apart from `'new'` (for example `'old'`), you can use `ng-switch` and choose alternative choices with `ng-switch-when="new"`

Answer (score 0):

Well you cant add inside of you div a `<label>` with a ng-if directive and type the next condition: ng-if="channel == 'new'". The code will looks like:

```
 <label ng-if="channel == 'new'"> will be available asap </label>
```